# Write as CSV giving weird characters

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, file-encodings

I am trying to write a dataframe as csv, which succeeds, but end up some fields with weird characters, Say for example 4.5×10−7 gives 4.5Ã—10âˆ’7 in the csv file. After doing few research I used fileEncoding as "Windows-1252", but that dint help. Here is a reproducible code

```
name <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
valuename <- c("4.5×10−7", "0.0006", "0.345")
df <- data.frame(name,valuename)
write.csv(df, "/Desktop/test.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Can anyone help me with a proper encoding or an alternative to take care of that field?

Comment: It works fine for me also when I tried.

Comment: Thats weird, In the csv file is the field 4.5×10−7 or 4.5Ã—10âˆ’7 ?

Comment: How are you viewing the CSV file? Perhaps your viewer doesn't support non-ASCII characters. What OS are you working on? Are you transferring the file between systems?

Comment: @Gerg It is 4.5×10−7. I think there is an issue with your CSV file.

Comment: @MrFlick we will be viewing it in excel.

Comment: @Santosh you are right. in textwrangler it shows as it is, but in excel its weird symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to force the fileEncoding to use "UTF-8":

`write.csv(df, "/Desktop/test.csv", row.names=FALSE, fileEncoding = 'UTF-8')`

Your code works fine in my windows 7, but I already had similar problems on my ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Looks like when I open in Xcel these weird characters come, but in text wrangler it looks exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `readr` package you can simply use:

`readr::write_excel_csv(df, file)`

Per the documentation this function "include[s] a UTF-8 Byte order mark which indicates to Excel the csv is UTF-8 encoded."